# A 'complicated' integral: $ \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, self-learning

I am calculating an integral $\displaystyle \int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}$ and I dont seem to be getting an answer.

When I integrate by parts twice, I get:
$$\displaystyle \int \limits _{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx = \left[\frac{\sin(x)\ln(x) - \frac{\cos(x)}{x}}{2}\right ]_{-\infty}^{+\infty}$$

What will be the answer to that ?

Comment: You could use double integrals and switch limits. It is an improper integral. The answer is $\pi$.

Comment: @AnuragPallaprolu I looked it up on `Wolfram Alpha` and it said $\pi$. WHat is an improper integral ? :)

Comment: @LittleChild I think we could use a bit of wiki here. :)  Its an integral whose limits reach either infinities.

Comment: @AnuragPallaprolu Double integral = split the integral into two ??

Comment: @O.L. Perhaps you could explain briefly why this follows from your link?

Comment: Have you tried using the Residue Theorem?

Comment: @LittleChild Accepting answers is (of course) entirely up to the OP. However, in the present case, since you admitted in a comment that the posted answer did not help you, I wonder why you accepted this answer (... **7 minutes** after it got posted!). A consequence is that it makes other, perhaps more satisfying, answers **less** likely to be posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** From the viewpoint of [improper Lebesgue integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Improper_Riemann_integrals_and_Lebesgue_integrals) or in sense of Cauchy principal value is integral is legitimate. Integration by parts.
\begin{align}
\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \mbox{d} x
=
&
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int \limits_{-t}^{\frac{1}{t}}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \mbox{d} x
+
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int \limits_{\frac{1}{t}}^{t}\dfrac{\sin(x)}{x} \mbox{d} x
\\
=
&
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int \limits_{-t}^{\frac{1}{t}}\sin(x)(\log x)^\prime \mbox{d} x
+
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int \limits_{\frac{1}{t}}^{t}\sin(x)(\log x)^\prime\mbox{d} x
\\
\end{align}

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to take the limit that way. You can't take to 0 and to infinity in the same limit. Perhaps there's a rule that says when that's okay?

Comment: Yeah, it is bad form to compute these as a single limit. Once you know the integral converges, you can get the answer this way; but, without proving convergence, this can give you unfortunate results in some cases.

Comment: Oh, if I already know convergence then this will reproduce the result had I taken the limit using two limits?

Comment: Well this is a hint. Assuming that the integral converges and proceeding step by step by the definition of improper integral you get these equalities between steps.

Comment: How does this help to go toward the answer?

Comment: @i707107 uhm.. very little :)

Comment: @LittleChild: Well.. if this answer helped you very little, then why would you accept it? Using integration by parts on this integral only makes it more complicated. So, I even doubt that this answer helped you "very little". I recommend following the link and read answers there.

Comment: Since $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is even, then: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=2\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx=2\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}=\pi$